# Returning multiple values in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have this Excel file.
The layout is like this:

[Sheet1]

```
No | Alphabet | Fruit
1 | ABC | 
2 | DEF |
3 | GHI |
```

[Sheet2]

```
Alphabet | Fruit
ABC | apple
ABC | pear
DEF | vegetable
```

I'd like to fill in the 'Fruit' column(s) in Sheet1.

What I currently have is this (which I put in C2 and drag down):

```
=INDEX(list!$A:$B,MATCH($B2,list!$A:$A,0),2)
```

Unfortunately, this only gives me the first match for each alphabet, like this:

[Sheet1]

```
No | Alphabet | Fruit
1 | ABC | apple
2 | DEF | vegetable
3 | GHI | #N/A
```

What I want to do is (in Sheet1) to return all matches under Fruit and replace 'vegetable' and '#N/A' to 'NIL', like this:

[Sheet1]

```
No | Alphabet | Fruit
1 | ABC | apple | pear
2 | DEF | NIL
3 | GHI | NIL
```

Comment: What happens when DEF has both vegetable and fruit?  Return one and NIL on the other? Or does this never happen?

Comment: If that happens, only return the fruit(s). It does happen, but I totally forgot about that scenario until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

The following array formula will do somewhat what you want:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4<>"Vegetable")*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4=$A1)*(COUNTIFS($A1:A1,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4)=0),0)),"")
```

It will return a null string instead of `NIL`

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when Exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

The reason I went with `""` instead of `"NIL"` is that this formula is designed to be drug/copied across and down.  It would fill every cell with `NIL` where the formula is not a fruit.

[image]

Comment: Can't get it to work. I noticed it's probably because your Sheet1 is missing the first row and column. I've tried to edit the letters in the formula but still getting errors.

Comment: Also, could you make it such that the formula selects entire columns instead of just the table, because the full data is in the thousands.

Comment: If your data is in the thousands you will need VBa. These array formulas in that quantity will kill excel. If it is not working I bet you did not use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode. You should not use full column references in array formulas.